# Sharing internet connection from ethernet to wifi NOT using apple sharing

Tags: wifi

I want to share my internet connection on 2 pcs (imac+mac mini), however, the default internet connection sharing stuff, is really unstable.
Is there any 3rd part alternative, working stable?

Thanks.

Comment: I think you are asking for how to achieve your chosen solution, rather than describing your problem and seeing what people come up with - that may be fixing your unstable connection, or supplying an alternative.  I'm just pointing this out as you are a new user so you may not be familiar with the best way to ask questions on here for maximum answer-potential.  With this in mind, I would suggest editing your question a little to incorporate other possible solutions.  Welcome, by the way :)

Answer (score 2):

i've personally never seen any 3rd party apps.

If you really want a stable connection i'd recommend buying a cheap router. I don't think the wifi module in mac's are good enough to share a connection reliably.

Comment: i already have a (great) wifi router, but for reasons i find it hard to explain (nothing that could be fixed hardware/software) i can't use it. So in your opinion the point is the cheap hardware in the mac itself. Well, that's interesting, thanks.

Comment: Just an opinion, but i've had the same issues as you before with sharing over wireless.

Comment: You should include this key point about your problem with a wireless router within your original question. I guess you are most probably working in  a polluted wireless environment.

Answer (score 0):

## No need for *Internet Sharing*

Your Question and Comments are unclear.

If you have an Ethernet connection to the Internet, and you want multiple Macs to took up to that, get a small hub or switch and plug them in via Ethernet cable.

> [Internet]--[modem/router with NAT via Ethernet ports]--[hub/switch]--[ethernet cable]--[Mac]

If you want to connect those Macs via wifi, get a small router such as an [Apple AirPort Express](https://www.apple.com/airport-express/) and plug it into the Ethernet, and connect your Macs to the new wifi network.

> [Internet]--[modem/router via Ethernet port]--[Ethernet cable]--[wifi base station]--[wifi]--[Mac]

So no need for Apple’s software "Internet Sharing" feature.

If these do not work for you, you need more detailed explanation in your Question.